# How to split a path to subpaths and store it in std::vector?

Tags: c++, string, filesystems

My question is how could I split my main path into several separate sub-paths and store it in a vector or list?

**Example**

I have path for example:

```
Assets/A/B/C
```

And I need to break them into separate sub-paths (or just strings):

```
Assets
A
B
C
```

And then stores it in `std::vector`. The last part i know how to do just `push_back(s)` where `s` is each subpath/string, but how to get this `s`?

Is there such a possibility in the standard library `std::filesystem` or do I need to find positions of two slashes myself and get a string within the boundaries of the first and next slash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A std::filesystem::path is iterable, so you can simply write:

```
for(auto p:path)
    vector.push_back(p.string());
```

Or even shorter:

```
std::vector(path.begin(),path.end());
```

If you do not need strings, but a vector of subpaths is also accaptable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yes, it really worked!